# React Native socket.io not able to listen to "socket.on" listener

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to build a chat app and to produce realtime effect, I'm using `socket.io`, I developed my server in node/express and it's working perfect, but the problem is in react-native side, as I'm not able to render the messages when the `socket.on` is used (even though I'm doing it in correct way, I entered the correct dependency in the `useEffect`). Below is some of the code from my app, and I will confirm that some parts are working fine, something is wrong only just in the `useEffect` dependencies list.

Server side logic to listen/send message to target client ids:

```
socket.on('sendMessage', ({senderId, receiverId, text}) => {
        console.log(text); // getting the output as expected here.
        const user = Utility.getUser(users, receiverId);
        io.to(user.socketId).emit('getMessage', {
            senderId,
            text,
        });
    });
```

Client side / React Native side:

```
const socket = useRef();
    const [arrivalMessage, setArrivalMessage] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // connect to server/api link
        socket.current = io('...', {
            transports: ['websocket'],
        });
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.current.on('getMessage', data => {
            console.log('getmessages: ',data);
            setArrivalMessage({
                // matchId: matchId,
                senderId: data.senderId,
                text: data.text,
                createdAt: Date.now(),
                updatedAt: Date.now(),
            });
        });
    // SOMETHING IS WRONG HERE, as this useEffect block is not being executed even though I have mentioned "socket" in my dependency list.
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [socket]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // ensures we don't get any other user's msg
        arrivalMessage &&
        match.includes(arrivalMessage.senderId) &&
        setMessages((prev) => [...prev, arrivalMessage]);
    }, [arrivalMessage, match]);
```

So, something is wrong in the 2nd `useEffect` as this useEffect block is not being executed even though I have mentioned "socket" in my dependency list, and hence the chatlist is not updated.
Also, there are no error logs in console so it adds more difficulty to debug...

I would really appreciate if someone point out what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `useRef` for the socket instance... mutating reference doesn't re-render content of the component therefore it doesn't trigger the `useEffect`

Here is an example how to use sockets in hook

```
export function useSocket(
  url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL /* default URL */
) {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState<SocketType>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const io: SocketType = SocketClient(url).connect()
    setSocket(io)

    return () => {
      socket?.disconnect()
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])

  return socket
}

export function useSocketEvent(
  socket: SocketType,
  event: keyof SocketListenEventMap,
  callback: (...args: unknown[]) => void
) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!socket) {
      return
    }

    socket.on(event, callback)

    return () => {
      socket.off(event, callback)
    }
  }, [callback, event, socket])

  return socket
}

export function useMessagesSocket() {
  const [arrivalMessage, setArrivalMessage] = useState(null)
  const socket = useSocket(/* URL */)

  useSocketEvent(socket, 'getMessages', (data) =>
    setArrivalMessage({
      //...
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I was able to declare socket object outside the functional component and now I could access the socket correctly but I was getting `useEffect` state rendering error as mentioned here, please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70354852/17091737

Comment: answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70354852/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component-useeffect-react-na/70359135#70359135

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, IT IS WORKING SO SEAMLESS <3